# SquareUp SqPaymentForm() - how to allow 4 digit cvv for Amex?

Tags: javascript, square-connect

I have a payment form using SquareUp's SqPaymentForm(). It embeds iFrames into the checkout page. The problem is the CVV field only allows three digits. This is a problem for American Express card holders.

Being an iFrame hosted by squp, I cannot control that cvv field directly.
I've searched squp's docs and cannot find how to enable 4 digits. 
Does anyone know how to make squp allow 4 digits here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an AMEX credit card number is detected, the form automatically switches to allowing a 4 digit CVV. Otherwise it will restricts to 3 digits.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It does not update the Placeholder though.

Comment: Correct, so its wise to have a placeholder with something generic like "CVV" rather than example of something like "123" since it _could_ be an AMEX.

Comment: This creates all sorts of escalating UI issues. I don't want the box blank because users don't know it's an input. I don't want to duplicate the title ("CVV2"). If I remove the title above the box and the value is pre-filled, user's don't know what the input is for. "xxx or xxxx" would look clumsy. Blarg!